# Can't migrate ruby windows to ruby cygwin

Tags: windows-8.1, cygwin, ruby, rubygems

On my windows 8.1+cygwin install, I had an windows ruby install. As I use mostly cygwin and cygwin and non-cygwin tools tend not to work well with each other, I wanted to move ruby to cygwin.

Unfortunately, installing ruby in cygwin yields a `ruby` command that fails:

```
$ ruby
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
         from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-cygwin]
```

Also there's no `gem` command.

There is no ruby related thing in my environment:

```
$ set | grep -i ruby
(no result)
```

Perhaps something is remaining from the original windows ruby install? I have uninstalled using the "add or remove programs" windows feature.

I've tried googling the problem, reinstaling cygwin's ruby, but didn't find any solution. On my second windows10+cygwin install, `ruby` and `gem` work great on cygwin.

Comment: Might be you have better luck asking this on the mailing lists at www.cygwin.com

Comment: There are some answers in SO that suggest how to make Cygwin + native Windows Ruby coexist nicely, for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/4260598/1040245